# Creating Google Alerts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dom, google-alerts

I have a program that creates a new google alert using HTMLdocuments in C#. This was workign perfectly but Google have recently changed their website. I've changed the code to try and match the new website, it no longer crashes but it doesn't actually create the alert in google.

The code is the following;

```
webBrowserControl.Navigate("http://www.google.com/alerts");

HtmlDocument createAlertPage = (HtmlDocument)webBrowserControl.Document;

var queryBox = createAlertPage.GetElementById("query_div");
queryBox.SetAttribute("value", _newAlertSearchString);

HtmlElement createButton = (HtmlElement)createAlertPage.GetElementById("create_alert");
createButton.InvokeMember("click");
```

Can anyone see where I have went wrong?

Thanks all.

Comment: There is another input element inside div#query_div, you need to get it and set the value there

Comment: Do you mean the entity_div or the explanation_text? I'm confused over the two. Thanks.

Comment: there is an input right after entity_div, it doesn't have id

Comment: Is this..

<inputtype ="text" class ="explanation_text">

Comment: I tried the following...

var queryBox = createAlertPage.GetElementById("query_div");
queryBox.SetAttribute("explanation_text", _newAlertSearchString);

Comment: you need to set value of the input, explanation_text is not id, but class

Comment: is there a way to set the value if it doesnt have a id?

Comment: I guess you could get it as a child at specific index from queryBox object

Comment: @Robert Hello, i still dont understand what you mean :(are you able to go to this link  http://www.google.com/alerts and inspect the element to highlight the attribute we need please. We did initially use Focus_elt as the attribute but we can no longer use this after the update

Regards